# How to connect to server on Docker from host machine?

Tags: docker

Ok, I am pretty new to `Docker` world. So this might be a very basic question.

I have a container running in Docker, which is running RabbitMQ. Let's say the name of this container is "Rabbit-container".

RabbitMQ container was started with this command:

```
docker run -d -t -i --name rmq -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Python script command with 2 args:

```
python ~/Documents/myscripts/migrate_data.py amqp://rabbit:5672/ ~/Documents/queue/
```

Now, I am running a `Python` script from my host machine, which is creating some messages. I want to send these messages to my "Rabbit-container". Hence I want to connect to this container from my host machine (Mac OSX).

Is this even possible? If yes, how?

Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: By running the command `docker run -d -t -i --name rmq -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management` and more specifically the option `-p 5672:5672` request the Docker daemon to bind your host-ip port 5672 with the container port 5672. Hence, if you try from the host to `nc 127.0.0.1 5672` you'll see that `nc` connected to the RabbitMQ socket. You can communicate with it through the network local stack using this socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I solved it by simply mapping the RMQ listening port to host OS:

```
docker run -d -t -i --name rmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

I previously had only `-p 15672:15672` in my command. This is mapping the Admin UI from Docker container to my host OS. I added `-p 5672:5672`, which mapped RabbitMQ listening port from Docker container to host OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this container in your local OSX system then you should find your default docker-machine ip address by running:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Then you can change your python script to point to that address and mapped port on `<your_docker_machine_ip>:5672`.

That happens because docker runs in a virtualization engine on OSX and Windows, so when you map a port to the host, you're actually mapping it to the virtual machine.

Comment: Didn't work. Also, I wasn't running `docker-machine` until this point. Why is it necessary?

Comment: In the official dockerhub image page https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ says that rabbitmq:3-management runs on port 15672. Stop your container, remove it and run it again mapping ports correctly and access it by `http://<docker-machine-ip>:15672`. Check official docs for more on docker-machine https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Comment: @Bhushan Is `default` listed as `running` when you run `docker-machine ls`? Although you don't see `docker-machine` when you install docker on OSX, this is how the boot2docker virtual [machine is setup and managed](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/fcdf7c37950dab9658556b1566b4363fa930878b/osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh).

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto: Thanks for the help. I solved the issue by mapping the RMQ port to host OS.

Comment: @Matt: No, if I run `docker-machine ls`, `default` is not listed. I need to start `docker-machine` explicitly as `docker-machine start`, then I could see it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to run the container with port 5672 exposed, perhaps 15672 as well if you want WebUI, and 5671 if you use SSL, or any other port for which you add tcp listener in rabbitmq.
It would be also easier if you had a specific IP and a host name for the rabbitmq container. To do this, you'd need to create your own docker network

`docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet123`

After that start the container like so

`docker run -d --net mynet123--ip 172.18.0.11 --hostname rmq1 --name rmq_container_name -p 15673:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

note that with `rabbitmq:3-management` image the port 5672 is (well, was when I used it) already exposed so no need to do that. `--name` is for container name, and `--hostname` obviously for host name.

So now, from your host you can connect to `rmq1` rabbitmq server.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the issue by mapping the RMQ port to host OS.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have never used docker-machine before, so i assume you are using the Docker Beta for Mac (you should see the docker-icon in the menu bar at the top).

Your docker run command for rabbit is correct. If you now want to connect to rabbit, you have two options:

1. Wrap your python script in a new container and link it to rabbit:

   `docker run -it --rm --name migration --link rmq:rabbit -v ~/Documents/myscripts:/app -w /app python:3 python migrate_data.py`

   Note that we have to link `rmq:rabbit`, because you name your container `rmq` but use `rabbit` in the script.
2. Execute your python script on your host machine and use localhost:5672

   `python ~/Documents/myscripts/migrate_data.py amqp://localhost:5672/ ~/Documents/queue/`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, I am using Docker Beta. I solved my problem by mapping RMQ listening port to host OS. I am posting my finding as another answer.